# Auto Match Different Variants on Google Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I can successfully auto match players using the same variant with [setVariant](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.Builder.html#setVariant%28int%29) method on google play game services, but i would like to auto match players using different variants. Is there any way to do that?

For example: i would like to auto match male and female players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be configuring [Real-time Multiplayer Rooms for the players you are looking to match](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.html#createAutoMatchCriteria(int) and then use bitmasks to map the players to rooms.

You will then pass this bitmask into the API call to createAutomatchCriteria. The logical "and" of the players must be 1 in order for the match to work, from the docs:

"Exclusive bitmasks for the automatching request. The logical AND of each pairing of automatching requests must equal zero for auto-match. If there are no exclusivity requirements for the game, this value should just be set to 0."

For example, if you specify 1 for all men, and 2 for all women, and then men would only get matched with women.